# the argument type 'object' cant be assigned to parameter type String

Tags: flutter, dart, mapping

Learning work with Maps...Can't have access to the element specified?
what is the problem. please give me some links to read or watch working with Maps in flutter.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `as String`?

`questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String`

Answer (score 0):

Your class Question requires string parameter in constructor.

`questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String` would fix the issue.

Cleaner solution would be to define questions variable as `List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions` or even create a separate model for question to avoid double indexes.

```
class QuestionModel {
  String questionText;
  List<String> answers;

  QuestionModel({required this.questionText, required this.answers});
}
```

and the define questions as

```
List<QuestionModel> questions = [
  QuestionModel(
    questionText: "What is your favourite color?",
    answers: ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"],
  ),
  ...
];
```

to access the question from the list:

```
questions[_questionIndex].questionText
```

Answer (score 0):

```
questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'].toString();
```